# ValueError at /quiz/None/newquestion Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'

Tags: django

in my quiz app here is my views.py code

```
def NewQuiz(request):
    quizForm=forms.QuizForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        quizForm=forms.QuizForm(request.POST)
        if quizForm.is_valid():        
           quiz= quizForm.save(commit=False)
           quiz_id = quiz.id
        else:
            print("form is invalid")
        return redirect('quiz:new-question',quiz_id=quiz_id)
    return render(request,'quiz/createquiz.html',{'quizForm':quizForm})

#create new question
def NewQuestion(request,quiz_id):
    user = request.user
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quizzes, id=quiz_id)
    questionForm=forms.QuestionForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        questionForm=forms.QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if questionForm.is_valid():
            question=questionForm.save(commit=False)
            #quiz=models.quiz.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('quizID'))
            question.quiz=quiz
            question.save() 
        else:
            print("form is invalid")
        return redirect('quiz:new-question',quiz_id=quiz_id)
    return render(request,'quiz/createqusetion.html',{'questionForm':questionForm})
```

and here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name="quiz"
urlpatterns = [
    path('quiz/newquiz', views.NewQuiz, name='new-quiz'),
    path('quiz/<quiz_id>/newquestion', views.NewQuestion, name='new-question'),
    path('quiz/<quiz_id>/quizdetail', views.QuizDetail, name='quiz-detail'),
    path('quiz/<quiz_id>/take', views.TakeQuiz, name='take-quiz'),
    path('check-marks/<quiz_id>', views.check_marks_view,name='check-marks'),
    path('quiz/calculate-marks', views.calculate_marks_view,name='calculate-marks'),
    path('calculate-marks', views.calculate_marks_view,name='calculate-marks'),
    path('check-marks/<int:pk>', views.check_marks_view,name='check-marks'),
    
]
```

and i got the above error i tray to change the path to like int:quiz_id but the error is still the same any who can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

remove commit = False. when you use commit = False. then it will return an object that hasn't yet been saved to the database which means it doesn't have id yet.

you don't need to assign id. just call save method assigning id

**UPDATE**

```
def NewQuiz(request):
    quizForm=forms.QuizForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        quizForm=forms.QuizForm(request.POST)
        if quizForm.is_valid():        
           quiz= quizForm.save()
           quiz_id = quiz.id
           return redirect('quiz:new-question',quiz_id=quiz_id)
        else:
            print("form is invalid")
    return render(request,'quiz/createquiz.html',{'quizForm':quizForm})
```

Comment: i removed that one but still the problem is here

Comment: @habtihabtamu your form is getting invalid then. check update on my answer.

Comment: yeah i used that one means i removed the commit =false but the error is still here

Comment: have you also used return redirect('quiz:new-question',quiz_id=quiz_id) after saving form and not after else: print('form is invalid')